# Button Fade In/Out glitching/not working.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, fade

I want to make a button that will appear after the user scrolls `screen.availheight` but disappear after the user hits the bottom, which I want it to be `(screen.availheight * 5)`.
My button seems to be glitching and not working occasionally. Here's my code;

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var offset1 = (screen.availHeight);
    var offset2 = (screen.availHeight * 5);
    var duration2 = 500;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset1){
            jQuery('.gdb').fadeIn(duration2);
        } else {
            jQuery('.gdb').fadeOut(duration2);
        }
    });
});
```

NOTE: I removed the code that made by button glitch. With the code above the button only appears after the user scrolls `offset1`

Comment: why are you using `availheight` ?

Comment: I making a full-windowed div at the top of the page that has it's height set to be `availheight`. So after the user passes that div I want my button to appear.

Answer (score 0):

May be this piece of code works for you.

```
if($(document)[0].scrollHeight>0 && $(document)[0].scrollHeight < $(document).height()){
$('.gdb').fadeIn();
}

elseif($(document)[0].scrollHeight == $(document).height()){
$('.gdb').fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
var btn_visible = 0;//used this variable so that button fadeIn/fadeOut does not fire unnecessary

$( window ).scroll(function(e) {

    var offset1 = (screen.availHeight);
    var offset2 = (screen.availHeight * 2);
    var duration2 = 500;

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset1 && $(this).scrollTop() < offset2 && btn_visible==1){
        jQuery('.gdb').fadeOut(duration2);
        btn_visible = 0;
    } else if($(this).scrollTop() > offset2 && btn_visible==0){
        $('.gdb').fadeIn(duration2);
        btn_visible = 1;
    }
});
```